# sql create table and data precision

Tags: python, sql

I'm sorry for that simple question. But I really do not find the mistake of this sql-statement (python):

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE measure_%s (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ztime int(11), mvalue DOUBLE)', (ptype,))
```

"mvalue" has values like 12.34. That means two decimals and values from 0 to 40. So I guess DOUBLE is the correct one...

This one works:

```
sql = """CREATE TABLE measure_"""+ptype+""" (
 id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 ztime int(11),
 mvalue FLOAT(5,2) )"""
cursor.execute(sql)
```

But I still do not see the difference to the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DBAPI placeholders for values, but not table manipulation statements.

That is, `"CREATE TABLE {}".format('mytable')` (Python formatting),

but `cur.execute("insert into people values (?, ?)", (who, age))` -- database quoting, which understands the different types.

http://ianhowson.com/a-quick-guide-to-using-mysql-in-python.html

Comment: How would you write my first statement in a correct way ('cause there are both things)?